# Can the same MATLAB Setup be used to install software on Windows as well as Linux?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, matlab

I have MATLAB R2015a installed in my Windows 10. I recently got the linux setup from a friend for installing MATLAB on Ubuntu, which turned out be R2011a version. I was wondering if the same 2015a setup that I have on my Windows be used to install MATLAB on Ubuntu also. In that case, I would happily discard the 2011a installer.

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

The 2 systems are fundamentally different and the contents of both installers therefor are not the same.